# ForwardRef warning React-hook-forms with Material UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to build a form with react-hook-forms with Material UI's inputs (my custom variant of TextField in this case). Although the form seems to work completely fine, it triggers a warning message in the console when rendering the form.

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to
> access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

I am using react-hook-form's Controller to wrap my TextField (as suggested by the docs)

Any suggestions or solutions are very welcome!

Below both the TextField component and the form where this issue occurs:

**Component TextField**

```
const TextField = props => {
    const {
        icon,
        disabled,
        errors,
        helperText,
        id,
        label,
        value,
        name,
        required,
        ...rest
      } = props;

    const classes = useFieldStyles();
    
    return (
        <MuiTextField 
            {...rest}
            name={name}
            label={label}
            value={value || ''}
            required={required}
            disabled={disabled}
            helperText={helperText}
            error={errors}
            variant="outlined" 
            margin="normal" 
            color="primary"
            InputProps={{
                startAdornment: icon,
                classes: {
                    notchedOutline: classes.outline,
                },
            }}
            InputLabelProps={{
                className: classes.inputLabel,
            }}
        />
    )
};

TextField.propTypes = {
    icon: PropTypes.node,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.any,
    required: PropTypes.bool,
    helperText: PropTypes.string,
};

export default TextField;
```

**Component LoginForm**

```
const LoginForm = () => {
    const { handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = values => console.log(values);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Typography variant="h5" color="primary" gutterBottom>
                Login
            </Typography>

            <Box py={3} height="100%" display="flex" flexDirection="column">
                <Controller
                    as={TextField}
                    label="Username"
                    name="username"
                    control={control}
                    errors={errors}
                    required
                />

                <Controller
                    as={TextField}
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    control={control}
                    errors={errors}
                    required
                />

                <Link>
                    Forgot your password?
                </Link>
            </Box>

            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use `Controller`'s render prop instead of `as`, because TextField's exposed ref is actually called inputRef, while `Controller` is trying to access `ref`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Header from "./Header";
import { TextField, ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import "./styles.css";
import ButtonsResult from "./ButtonsResult";

let renderCount = 0;

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

const defaultValues = {
  TextField: "",
  TextField1: ""
};

function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, reset, control } = useForm({ defaultValues });
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  renderCount++;

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => setData(data))} className="form">
        <Header renderCount={renderCount} />
        <section>
          <label>MUI TextField</label>
          <Controller
            render={(props) => (
              <TextField
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                inputRef={props.ref}
              />
            )}
            name="TextField"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
          />
        </section>

        <section>
          <label>MUI TextField</label>
          <Controller
            render={(props) => (
              <TextField
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                inputRef={props.ref}
              />
            )}
            name="TextField1"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
          />
        </section>

        <ButtonsResult {...{ data, reset, defaultValues }} />
      </form>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

you can click the following link for actual behavior, now with ref assigned properly with Controller, we can successfully focus on the field when there is an error for better accessibility.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-focus-74ecu

Comment: Thank you Bill, i also took this approach later on and this does indeed prevent difficulties with Ref. I also figured out that previous versions of react-hook-form (v 6.0.8) do not have this behaviour when using the 'as' prop

Comment: yes, that's correct. we introduced that extra `ref` prop at 6.10.0 to improve focus management. https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

The warning is completely right as suggested by the official docs it think you did not reach to the functional components part.  [Link to the offical docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

**You cannot give ref to functional components as they do not have instances**

If you want to allow people to take a ref to your function component, you can use `forwardRef` (possibly in conjunction with `useImperativeHandle`), or you can convert the component to a class.

**You can, however, use the `ref` attribute inside a function component as long as you refer to a DOM element or a class component like this:**

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  const textInput = useRef(null);
  
  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```